# Can I use my own file extension for Django Templates and still include django.contrib.auth.urls?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I can easily just use `html.djt` as i wish, but only if i let the built-in class based views know which template i want to use. A custom extension allows me to configure my editor to recognize django templates, which helps with code formatting and highlighting etc.

In this example i would need to reference a template using `template_name`:

```
path(
    "login/",
    auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name="registration/login.html.djt"),
    name="login",
),
```

It can be handy to include all the url authentication patterns like this:

```
from django.urls import path, include
    # ...
urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

However is it still possible to use a custom file extensions for the templates if i include the built-in url patterns?

Comment: No, if you wish to do that you would have to write each url yourself (Unless you go and make a custom include function or something). But why even have that custom extension? What you do can be done _without_ any custom file extensions. There are many plugins you would find in the various IDEs,. You can simply configure your IDE settings for your project to have HTML be considered as Django templates, etc.

Comment: Personally i think a custom extension is useful because i don't want to treat regular html files the same way as i treat django templates. Particularly runnig my code through code formatters is part of my workflow and i can not format django templates with the same tool as html files. Having the same extension forces me to tell my editor that this is a django template manually or format my code manually. This discussion seems to be not so popular or seen important: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/2614. I only could find a very old closed ticket. Ruby on Rails uses `html.erb` for example.